# printerplusplus not creating the vitual printer

Tags: windows, printers, virtual-printer

I am using [Printer++](http://www.printerplusplus.com/Download) for the virtual printer. All was working fine. To rename the printer I uninstalled the printer++ and removed the printer from the devices list. When I tried to add it back, the application is installing but the printer is not showing in the devices and printers. This is the log file message.

4/22/2016 2:41:50 PM - Install Started.
4/22/2016 2:41:50 PM - PrinterName: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
4/22/2016 2:41:50 PM - Setting Driver Path and Files.
4/22/2016 2:41:50 PM - Adding Printer Monitor.
4/22/2016 2:41:50 PM - Adding Printer Port.
4/22/2016 2:41:50 PM - Exception: Could not open printer for the monitor port PrinterPlusPlus!
4/22/2016 2:41:50 PM - Source: AddVPrinter
Message: Could not open printer for the monitor port PrinterPlusPlus!
InnerException: System.Exception: Could not open printer for the monitor port PrinterPlusPlus!
   at PrinterPlusPlusSetupCustomAction.SpoolerHelper.AddVPrinter(String printerName, String key)
4/22/2016 2:41:50 PM - Source: AddVPrinter
Message: Source: AddVPrinter
Message: Could not open printer for the monitor port PrinterPlusPlus!
InnerException: System.Configuration.Install.InstallException: Source: AddVPrinter
Message: Could not open printer for the monitor port PrinterPlusPlus! ---> System.Exception: Could not open printer for the monitor port PrinterPlusPlus!
   at PrinterPlusPlusSetupCustomAction.SpoolerHelper.AddVPrinter(String printerName, String key)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at PrinterPlusPlusSetupCustomAction.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
4/22/2016 2:41:50 PM - Install Finished.

Comment: did you find any solution ???

Comment: no i coulnt find any, tried almost everything best I know.

Comment: hey what i find that printer ++ not supporting Windows 8 and 8.1 (don't know about windows 10 I haven't try on that). You can try on windows 7 it should work. Also I find printer ++ is worst, unmanageable and also not trustworthy it is having lots of bugs and cant be used in any application. But the main pain is we don't have any other option.